# Liquibase Diff Tool missing constraints

Tags: integration-testing, liquibase

We are using with my company Liquibase's diff tool to check schema relevancy of our clients MySQL and Oracle databases automatically via jUNIT tests. For that point Liquibase is great.

Our problem is that Liquibase seems to "miss" some Foreign Key renaming where other tools like SQL examiner or RedGate MySQL compare seem to find all the foreign key naming differences.

This feature is very important for us whereas we need to keep exact schema consistency for maintenance operations (DROP foreign_key, etc.)

Is there a way to put an option to Diff.compare() method in java to show this kind of inconstancies ?

```
final Diff locResultDiff = new Diff(_referenceDatabase, _cibleDatabase);
_diffResult = locResultDiff.compare();
```

Or can someone propose other solutions to make these tasks ?

Comment: One solution I found is to redefine the equals method in the class liquibase.database.structure.ForeignKey;

Just add 
     `&& name.equals(that.getName());`
at the end of the equals method